# SQL Server 2012: MAX on varchar columns not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using aggregates like **MAX** on **varchar** columns. When I execute a simple select on a varchar column, I get 4 characters value which is **"övrö"**. In that column I found lots of values that are much bigger in length. My understanding is that it should return a value like **"asdfsadfasdfasdfsadfsdafsdafsadfasdfsadfasdf"**.

Please correct me if I am misunderstanding/misusing MAX as I have to use this concept in a complicated SQL to avoid duplicate records.

If MAX on varchar gets top record based on alphabetical order, how come it still causing the duplicate values if I use it for specific columns (#2 and 3 as shown in the attached image. Red border area is showing duplicates, which should just be a single row.

[image: RESULTS]

**EDIT - ISSUE RESOLVED**

The problem was that I was adding the string columns Aggregates in Group By clause, when removed, duplicates are gone!!!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `max()` works based on alphabetical ordering, not length.

Answer (score 1):

Min and max get the maximal values. For varchar, it's not the length, but imagine them as sorted alphabetically. Max takes the last element while min takes the first.

If you want to take the maximum length, you need max(length( column ))